# Parsing Street Address Oracle and remove unwanted texts

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm newbie to Oracle and I have a requirement to parse US Street address from a string, I tried couple of options with regexp substr, but didn't give me desired result.

Here is few example from text string.

xyz 123 se stark st suit 401
xyx 123 39th ave ne 2nd flr n-3
xyz 213 nebraska courage way e-1

And my output should be:
123 se stark st
123 39th ave ne
213 nebraska courage way

My SQL so far :

```
SELECT UPPER (
          REGEXP_SUBSTR (REPLACE ('xyz 2551 38th ave ne tc 2', 'xyz '),
                         '((^[0-9]{1,9}+[ ]+[0-9]{1}[/]+[0-9]{1})|(^[0-9]+))'))
          AS houseno,  
       TRIM (
          UPPER (
             REGEXP_SUBSTR (
                REPLACE ('xyz 2551 38th ave ne tc 2', 'xyz '),
                '[^0-9]+((1( )st|1st)|(2( )nd|2nd)|(3( )rd|3rd)|([1234567890]+( )th|[1234567890]+th)) +(ave(nue)?|st(reet)?|boulevard|blvd)[[:print:]]*|P(.)O(.)( )+Box( )[0-9]+|[a-z][[:print:]]*',
                1,
                1,
                'i')))
          AS street_addrerss,    
       UPPER (REPLACE ('xyz 2551 38th ave ne tc 2', 'xyz ')) AS orginal_text
  FROM DUAL;
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: This sounds unfair. Extracting an address from strings like you show is a very difficult problem - they gave it to a newbie in Oracle, with no suggestions as to how to go about solving it? How are you supposed to recognize what is the address and what is the "unnecessary text"? Did they give any rules for that?

Comment: The requirement is to extract the street address from string and load this data into Oracle DB. They aren't worried about the address line 2.

Comment: I thought my question was easy to understand, but I will try again. By looking at your input strings, how do you know where the street address (line 1) begins, and where it ends? For example: You may say "the address begins at the first digit in the string." Fair enough; does this mean you can't have any digits in the "garbage" BEFORE the address? Ever? OK, if that can be guaranteed, that's good and useful. Then, how do you determine where the address ENDS and the remaining "garbage" begins?

Comment: Input string have 3 letter prefix and which is 'garbage' and our address line 1 should start with digit (House Number), as you said we have no way to determine where address END's and where 'garbage' begins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a somewhat general approach... it assumes the address begins at the first digit in the string (so the "useless" text before the address may never contain digits), and the address always ends with st, str, street, av, ave, avenue, way, rt, route, blvd, with or without a period after them. You will have to maintain this list, as there are many other possibilities.

It also assumes everything in the input string is in lower-case (if not, you can apply lower_case to the input string, and then initcase to the resulting address - I won't worry about that). If you DON'T want the terminal period (.), regardless of whether an address contains it or not, you can delete .? from the end of the search string.

```
with
     input_strings ( str ) as (
       select 'xyz 123 se stark st suit 401'     from dual union all
       select 'xyx 123 39th ave ne 2nd flr n-3'  from dual union all
       select 'xyz 213 nebraska courage way e-1' from dual union all
       select '2 new way blvd. apt 33'           from dual
     )
select regexp_substr(str, '\d.*(st|str|street|av|ave|avenue|way|rt|route|blvd).?') 
                                                                               as address
from   input_strings
;

ADDRESS
------------------------------
123 se stark st
123 39th ave
213 nebraska courage way
2 new way blvd.
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. I added remaining possible end strings and could see desired result.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want to return everything after the first space up until space number 5.

Position of first space is: `instr(<string>,' ',1,1)`
Position of 5th space is: `instr(<string>,' ',1,5)`

Use the substr function to get the part of the string you need.

```
select substr('xyz 123 se stark st suit 401'
             ,instr('xyz 123 se stark st suit 401', ' ') + 1
             ,instr('xyz 123 se stark st suit 401', ' ', 1, 5) - instr('xyz 123 se stark st suit 401', ' ') - 1)
  from dual
```

Comment: This is not a viable solution, I agree it work with certain scenarios but not all of the data that I have.